# KNative Service unable to download Hello World image from Docker HUB

Tags: docker, kubernetes, knative, knative-serving

I am working on a Kubernetes I deployed on my Mac using Vagrant and Vbox.
Then I installed Istio, Knative Serving, and Eventing.

I then defined a `service.yaml` file with the following content:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: hello-k8s-ns

---
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-k8s
  namespace: hello-k8s-ns
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: sasadangelo/hello-k8s
```

where sasadangelo/hello-k8s is a Hello World!!! docker application I built and deployed on Docker HUB. My problem is that when I try to deploy it with the `kubect apply` command, everything goes fine but no Pod is deployed. I see the service deployed but when I analyze it with `kubect describe` I see the following error message:

```
Revision "hello-k8s-lm6hk" failed with message: Unable to fetch image "sasadangelo/hello-k8s": failed to resolve image to digest: failed to fetch image information: Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 54.72.52.58:443: connect: connection refused.
```

It's not clear to me why it cannot download the image from Docker HUB. My Vagrant VM access to the Internet correctly and the command:

```
kubectl run hello-k8s --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=sasadangelo/hello-k8s:latest --port=80
```

works fine.

Since I am new to Knative I suspect I missing something in Knative configuration. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you follow [these](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/deploying/private-registry/) steps ?

Comment: are you running the kubectl run command in namespace hello-k8s-ns ?

Comment: @mario hank you. This was the problem.

Comment: @Salvatore D'angelo, so what was exactly the issue ? You've omitted this part of the configuration at all ? You can share it as an answer as it might be useful for others if they encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mario's reply, I solved configuring Docker HUB credentials.
Here the [procedure](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/deploying/private-registry/).

I think KNative for some reason don't simply pull the image but it does some additional stuff (i.e. verify digest) that requests Docker HUB authentication.

According to the procedure linked, if you give the command:

```
kubectl create secret mysecret ...
```

Then you need to modify the `service.yaml` in this way:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: hello-k8s-ns

---
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-k8s
  namespace: hello-k8s-ns
spec:
  template:
  spec:
    containers:
      - image: sasadangelo/hello-k8s
  imagePullSecrets:  # <--------------- Add this line
    - name: docker-hub-registry # <---- Add this line
```